# $G$ is a cyclic group with $a$ as generator. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism on $G$. Prove that $\phi(a)$ is also a generator of $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I tried to prove this and if you can verify or enhance the argument, please do. I found this problem on Elements of Modern Algebra by Gilbert and Gilbert.

Proof:

Let $G$ be a cyclic group generated by $a$ and let $\phi$ be an automorphism on G. Then for any $x\in G$, there exists $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^r=x\Rightarrow \phi(a^r)=\phi(x)\Rightarrow \phi(a)^r=\phi(x)\in G.$ Since $r$ is an arbitrary integer and $\phi(x)$ is an arbitrary element of $G$, therefore, $\phi(a)$ is also a generator of $G.$

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241104/if-phi-g-rightarrow-h-is-a-group-homomorphism-and-g-is-cyclic-prove-tha

Comment: Note that $G=\phi(G)=\phi(\langle a\rangle)=\langle\phi(a)\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is mostly ok, but here is a proof that I find clearer:

Let $a$ be a generator for $G$. Take $g \in G$. We want to prove that $g$ is a power of $\phi(a)$.

Since $\phi$ is surjective, we have $g=\phi(x)$ for some $x\in G$.

Since $a$ is a generator for $G$, we have $x=a^r$ for some integer $r$.

Then, $g=\phi(x)=\phi(a^r)=\phi(a)^r$, as required.

Comment: Oh I can see it more clearly now. The arbitrary element part should be justified, so I have to use the fact that $\phi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove it can be the following:
If $a$ is a generator, then the order of $G$ is the same as the order of $a$; so as $\phi(a)$ is also an element of $G$, you can just prove that $\phi(a)$ and $a$ have the same order. 
If $o(a)=n$ and $\phi(a)^r=e$, that means that $a^r$ is in the kernel, so it has to be the identity, and thus it has to be a multiple of $n$. In other words, the order of $\phi(a)$ is also $n$.